# Even after doing all I could found - Keep on getting the typical Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' and Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

When I try to run cordova or ionic I keep on getting the error:

```
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

I have android SDK in `/opt/android-sdk`.
When I echo $ANDROID_HOME it returns `/opt/android-sdk` correctly.

When I echo $PATH it returns:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/android-sdk/tools:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/bin:/opt/gradle/bin:/opt/android-sdk/bin**
```

So the way I see it I have both paths to platform-tools and tools correctly added to PATH.

```
/opt/android-sdk/tools:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:
```

When I write android in the terminal it opens the Android SDK manager as it should.

So I started desperate mode and start changing the files: `~/.bashrc` & `~/.bash_profile` & `~/.profile`

I figure they all do the same. Which is setting the ANDROID_HOME env. path and the PATH. But if when I echo $ANDROID_HOME and $PATH all looks fine then what the eck I just start doing anything that I can find.

I nanoed `~/.bashrc` with:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk  
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin**
```

and executed `source ~/.bashrc`

I nanoed `~/.bash_profile` with:

```
#Android

export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/opt/android-sdk/tools  
export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
```

and executed `source ~/.bash_profile`

I nanoed `~/.profile`:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists  
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then  
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:/opt/android-studio/bin"  
fi  
export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk  
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-sdk/tools  
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools  
export PATH=$PATH:/bin  
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/bin  
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```

and executed `source ~/.profile`

That leaves me thinking something is wrong with android-sdk but actually the Android SDK manager is opening and uploading and displaying the right location on top.

So summing up I am desperately trying everything and this error keeps on popping up. Does anyone have any tip on what should I do next or undo?

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone I even got help online and noone could help me. I am just gonna say BYE UBUNTUTUTUTTUUTUT#

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after install with `umake android`.

Solved adding to .zshrc (.bashrc in your case):

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/username/opt/android-studio/bin"
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/username/Android/Sdk"
```

Are you using *npm* with ***sudo***?

If you installed one as a normal user and the other as sudo you could try to reinstall or add the paths to the root user.

[Install node without sudo.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version/12570971#12570971)